# Android: Creating a test project within a project causes "error occurred during build", any ideas?

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, adt, android-testing

I am using the latest version of eclipse (v4) and the latest version of the ADT plugin for eclipse.

Reading the docs, android suggests creating the test project within the same structure of the project i am creating but under a directory called tests (same level as the current src directory)

I have tried this a number of times and each time it gives me an error when i click finish.

> Element Not found, Error occurred during build.

I have created a number of other projects and took out all the spaces between project names, just in case this was causing a problem, and still the error keeps appearing.

Of course creating a test project outside of the current project works, but according to the docs the best place is to place the test project inside the project being tested.

Any i am missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific about _"I have tried this a number of times and each time it gives me an error when i click finish"_, what did you do and when did the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Android recommends keeping the tests in a separate project with a parallel directory structure that has test directories.  See [Test Projects under Testing Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects).  That documentation will guide you through creating a test project using ADT.

Comment: Read [the link](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects) carefully, what android recommend is _"You can create a test project anywhere in your file system, but the best approach is to add the test project so that its root directory tests/ is at the same level as the src/ directory of the main application's project."_

Comment: My error.  The link I should have used is http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_eclipse.html#CreateTestProjectEclipse which says "To set up a test environment for your Android application, you must first create a separate project that holds the test code."  So, the directory structure is as you describe, but the test project is a separate project with its own manifest, etc.